# Thank You email for recruitment

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, human-resources, email, careers

They told the HR manager will send me the job details and application forms. I was interviewed by the Project Manager and I didn't meet the HR manager. The thing is I was told to join on Friday for 1-month trial. Now I would like to send an email to the project manager thanking him for the interview and I want to ask do I need to provide him with any further details. How to go with the email?

Comment: Nothing special is needed here. "Thanks for bringing me on board; I'm really looking forward to working with you" will do just fine. You might also want to take the opportunity to ask whether there's anything in particular you should bring for your first day, or any other questions you might have. Congrats and good luck!

Answer (score 9):

> Dear XXX,
>
> Thank you for bringing me onboard. I am excited to join the team
>   and getting started.
>
> Please could you let me know if I have to provide any further
>   details on the first day.
>
> Looking forward to getting started with the team.
>
> regards, XYZ

---

A minor edit done with @JonStory's help from his comment below

Comment: Just a minor thing, and this may just be my preference, but I'd swap "Kindly" for "Please could you" - Kindly has a hint of a demand, rather than a request, and sounds slightly passive aggressive. Kindly tends to be used by non-native speakers, for some reason I've never worked out, but is pretty uncommon among native speakers (at least in the UK). We tend to use it sarcastically ("Kindly stop your dog weeing on my carpet")

Comment: @JonStory Thank you for pointing it out.  Made the edit.

Comment: @jon Story good point, "kindly" is widely used by non-native speakers and it is good to know it may confuse native speakers.